# Is there an online tool to check .NET application loading online?

Tags: .net, datagrid, performance-testing

Are there any tools to check the speed of a .NET application loading data using datagrid? In my application, I'm trying load a data of 20000 records with each has 15 fields.

Comment: What's the question here? You don't need a tool to determine if something is too slow, other than the one found in between your ears.

Answer (score 4):

My main suggestion would be to page your data.

There is no reason to load all 20,000 records immediately, as the user would never be able to see all 20,000 at once.  Load the first couple hundred, and page the rest as needed.  This will potentially dramatically improve your load times.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you should use a so called "[Performance profiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29)" tool for that.

There are several tools out there, e.g.:

- Red Gate's [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)
- Jet Brain's [dotTRACE profiler](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/)
- [Many more...](https://www.google.com/search?q=.net%20performance%20profiler)